# Json Response into a table overwriting

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have this template where I make a ajax call to get the price of medicine, I get a object of the data, the problems it that I can't show the data in the table, 'cause it overwrite the last value and other problem in that it doesn't let any other data in the table it erase all the data like nombre_medicamento or presentacion, it does a new table.
I'm working with Django and Python

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var data = $("#attendees tr.data").map(function (index, elem) {
    var ret = [];
        $('.inputValue', this).each(function () {
            var d = $(this).val()||$(this).text();
            ret.push(d);
            buscarprecio(d);
     });
     return ret;
});

function buscarprecio(idgrupo) {
      $.ajax({
            url: "/precio_search",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                grupname: idgrupo,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
                success: function (json) {

                var jsonResponse = eval(json);
                var tbl_body = "";
                       var tbl_row = "";
                 $.each(jsonResponse, function(index, element){

                      $.each(this, function(k , v) {
                        tbl_row += "<td>"+ jsonResponse[0]["fields"]["medicamento_precio"]+"      </td>";
                   })
                  tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
             })

                     $("#attendees tbody").html(tbl_body);
                 },
             error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(xhr.status + "  Inside error :    " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
     }

});
</script>
<table id="attendees" class="attendees">
<tbody>
<thead>
         <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center"><label>Nombre Del Medicamento</label></th>
                <th style="text-align: center"><label>Presentaciòn</label></th>
                <th style="text-align: center"><label>Precio</label></th>
                <th style="text-align: center"><label>Fecha En Que Se Extendio La  Receta</label></th>

          </tr>
            </thead>
             {% if formulario %}
                 {% for post in formulario %}
                 <tr class="data">
                    <td style="text-align: center" class="inputValue"> {{ post.nombre_medicamento_2.id}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"> {{ post.presentacion_3}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"  class="precio"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"> {{ post.receta_farmacos }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>
 </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem in your code is your are overwritting the table body with this line `$("#attendees tbody").html(tbl_body);`

You can use `$().append()` to add new rows to your table.

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for examples.